# How can I open FLAC files in iTunes without doing any kind of conversion?

Tags: itunes

I have done this before but it no longer works. Some combination of the XiphQT component and the FLAC Import component allows one to open FLAC files natively in iTunes. After an update I was no longer able to open FLAC files in iTunes. If this was directly related or not I do not know.

I've tried Fluke, which has been no help, especially since the SetOGG script no longer works on Mac OSX 10.6.

Here is the link for the XiphQT component: http://www.xiph.org/quicktime/download.html

The other component is called FLAC importer, available here:
http://people.xiph.org/~arek/flac_import/

PS: I use the FLAC files (all of which are legitimate rips or downloads to mix with. Keeping an extra copy of each in ALAC, MP3 or AAC format would just be a terrible waste).

**Conclusion**

The situation is pretty much helpless. iTunes will never support FLAC and it's unlikely that ALAC will be supported in all DJ'ing software (which is of particular interest to me and is why I asked the question). The situation is also made worse by the fact that FLAC files themselves com in with three different types of metadata:

- Native FLAC
- OGG
- ID3v2+

The good news is that I have found an alternative media player which is cross platform, has a similar feature and look: [Songbird](http://getsongbird.com).

Hopefully this question helps other people who also has this question. I also hope that if this situation improves that this question can be updated.

Comment: "After an update..." what kind of update? If it was an iTunes/OS X update, did you try reinstalling the two components afterwards?

Comment: Yes, I have several times without any success. Is there any sort of log that I can check to see if iTunes is loading the components?

Comment: If there were one, I'd imagine the place to look woud be in `Console` under the 'FILES' Heading, `~/Library/Logs` sub-heading. There may *be* something in there under XiphQT.

Comment: you can check for files an app is using via the `lsof` command in `Terminal.app`. `lsof | grep 'iTunes'` should do the trick.

Comment: I have since switched to the clementine player.

Answer (score 4):

> I've tried Fluke, which has been no
>   help, especially since the SetOGG
>   script no longer works on Mac OSX
>   10.6.

@Phillip Whelan Fluke has had 10.6 support since 2009. If you're experiencing issues with Fluke, which is considered the top offering at present, then I'd be curious about further inspection of the files or your system. Perhaps they are not 16bit/44.1KHz, or wrapped in the OGG Container?

Comment: Fluke is a hack, not a solution. I can get it to work for a single song but I can't be tagging hundreds of albums. The SetOGG script also does not work anymore. The reason it's not working might be a little too technical for this site (missing functions in the python API shipped with Mac OS X).

Comment: Correction: It's not a solution you like. iTunes doesn't support FLAC, plain and simple. Short of converting your FLAC files to another format with an offering like xAct (http://sourceforge.net/projects/xact/), there isn't much else in the way of options.

Comment: I'll try to get SetOGG working again soon with the changes in the Python SDK. My only other choice is to dump iTunes, plain and simple.

Comment: @PhilipWhelan - Apple's python includes all the standard library - what do you think is missing? as if not documented this is a bug